# JRI: obtain error messages from the R engine

Tags: java, r, rjava, jri

I am using [JRI](http://www.rforge.net/JRI) to execute a number of computations using the R engine. As pointed in various tutorials out there in the web I am using the [`eval` method](http://rforge.net/org/doc/org/rosuda/JRI/Rengine.html#eval(java.lang.String)) of the [`Rengine` class](http://rforge.net/org/doc/org/rosuda/JRI/Rengine.html), e.g.:

`engine.eval("meanVal=mean(rVector)");`

At some point the `eval` method starts returning `NULL`, which according to the documentation means "something went wrong". However, I can not identify in the `Rengine` class a property or a method that would provide an error message, error status or R console output to identify the cause. Is there any way to obtain detailed information on what might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

It is actually amazingly hard to get error information from R when embedding it. However, it does provide more information at R level. Hence  the simplest way is to wrap your code in

```
try(..., silent=TRUE)
```

or

```
tryCatch(..., error=function(e) e)
```

such that you get errors back to Java by regular evaluation. If you want to get really fancy, you can use `Rserve::Rserve.eval()` which can also return stack traces on errors but will require the latest version of the `Rserve` package from http://rforge.net/Rserve

Comment: That code is not Java, but in any case, the `engine.eval()` method is not issuing exceptions. As I wrote in the question, the only clue of a problem is this method returning `NULL`.

Comment: Exactly, that's why I was pointing out that you want to catch it in the R side - see above - as you can't on the the Java side since R won't give you that unless you ask.

Comment: Now I understand it must be the code passed to `engine.eval()` to be wrapped; you might wish to edit you answer to make it clearer. In any case, this way I get `[NULL]` instead of just `NULL`.